# How can I fetch and paginate all the pictures of all the posts with GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I have access to my blog data via GraphQL, which I have no experience with. I have an endpoint for posts but not for images. I can't change this API.

Each post can have between 0 and N pictures. This is a simplified query for posts:

```
query {
  posts {
    title
    pictures {
      uri
      width
      height
    }
  }
}
```

I want to fetch all the pictures of all the posts with pagination (offset and limit).

In essence, I want to replicate the result of doing this in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM pictures LIMIT 0, 10
```

And ideally I'd like to retrieve the total number pictures too.

For example, if I have two posts with 7 pictures each, and I set the limit to 10 and the offset to 0, I should be able to fetch all the pictures of the first one and 3 of the second one. Then I could do a second request with an offset of 10, and that should return the 4 remaining pictures of the second post.

Is this at all possible with GraphQL? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a wrapper type that allows for other fields related to pagination because graphql only allows the returning of known/defined fields

Here's an example from a project I worked on prior:

```js
gql`
  type UserQueryResult {
    page: PositiveInt!
    total: PositiveInt!
    numPages: PositiveInt!
    resultsPerPage: PositiveInt!
    hasNextPage: Boolean!
    hasPreviousPage: Boolean!
    results: [User!]!
  }
`
```

That way in your `Query` definition you can return the new paginated type.

```js
gql`
type Query {

  """
  Returns users that match the given query
  """
  searchUsers(
    """
    A string used to filter users
    """
    query: String! = ""

    """
    The page requested, if the query has more than one page of results.
    """
    page: PositiveInt! = 1

    """
    Number of results on each page. Must be between 1 and 50. Default is 9
    """
    resultsPerPage: PositiveInt! = 9
  ): UserQueryResult!
}

`
```

And from your client when you're querying you can do:

```js
const USER_QUERY = gql`
  query ($page: PositiveInt!, $query: String!) {
    searchUsers(page: $page, query: $query) {
      numPages
      page
      total
      results {
        id
        name
        email
        adminPrivileges
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: For your example, you can swap out the page and resultsPerPage variable with offset and limit if you prefer but the idea is still the same